# Checking if an element exist in list

Tags: python, pandas, list-comparison

I have 2 lists(pandas.core.series.Series) and I want to list elements that doesn't exist in the other series. So I'm using 'not in' operator but it doesn't work and the code prints the whole list instead.

```
for i in list1:
  if i not in list2:
    print(i)
```

This code prints the whole list1 instead of printing elements that don't exist in list2. I know this should be a simple task but I'm stuck, can someone help me?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with a little amount of sample data to reproduce the issue. Give the expected output and actual output

Comment: A `pd.Series` **is not a list**

Comment: Next time, please provide some example data like @Golden Lion did: `list1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]); list2 = pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7, 8])` as well as the expected output `1 2 3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use sets and calculate the set difference.

```
set(list1).difference(set(list2))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Pandas own `Series.isin()`:

```
list1[~list1.isin(list2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I demonstrate isin using ~ which means not in.  The isin build a mask of true of false values then applied to the dataframe

```
list1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
list2 = pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

print(list1[~list1.isin(list2)])
```

output

1
2
3

values of list1 are not in list2